# Can't connect to Windows Server 2012 Virtual Machine in Red Hat 6

Tags: networking, redhat, windows-server-2012, kvm-virtualization

I have installed a WS2012R2 virtual machine using KVM on Red Hat, It has a bridge connection, Both (Host and Guest) have public IP addresses, both have internet access, both can ping any ip address or website (local or remote), if I check the public IP address using a website like www.whatismyip.com, it shows properly the public adresses of both machines. But I can't ping the virtual machine public IP address from anywhere, nor the host. I tried disabling both firewalls and nothing, I also tried IP forwading in sysctl.conf uncommenting net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 with no results. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance